# youtube: link to display HD video by default

Tags: video, hyperlink, youtube

Is there a way to link a youtube video so that it plays automatically in HD?

I've tried several things (adding &hd=1, &vq=hd720) but none of them works

For example: 
https://www.youtube.com/v/BH_lZSTYFHs&hd=1

It starts always as 480p, it does not care apparently about the hd=1 parameter in the url

Comment: This question better fits https://superuser.com website.

Comment: The only way at the moment is adding the `version=3` and the `vq=hd720` parameter. Note that the author of the video you are linking doesn't allow playing his content in this way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

via [Is there a way to link someone to a YouTube Video in HD 1080p quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145257/is-there-a-way-to-link-someone-to-a-youtube-video-in-hd-1080p-quality)

> Yes there is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/Susj4jVWs0s?version=3&vq=hd720
```

> options are:

```
default|none: vq=auto;
Code for auto: vq=auto;
Code for 2160p: vq=hd2160;
Code for 1440p: vq=hd1440;
Code for 1080p: vq=hd1080;
Code for 720p: vq=hd720;
Code for 480p: vq=large;
Code for 360p: vq=medium;
Code for 240p: vq=small;
```

As mentioned, you have to use the `/embed/` or `/v/` URL.

**Note:** Some copyrighted content doesn't support be played in this way

Comment: As of now, this seems not to work anymore. When I open the URL above, I get the video playing at 480p (higher resolutions possible to set manually on this stupid settings button).

Comment: also it is not worked with other parameters like hiding controls with hd

Answer (score 11):

Nick Vogt at H3XED posted this syntax:
https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?version=3&vq=hd1080

Take this link and replace the expression "VIDEOID" with the (shortened/shared) ID of the video.

Exapmple for ID: i3jNECZ3ybk looks like this: ... /v/i3jNECZ3ybk?version=3&vq=hd1080

What you get as a result is the standalone 1080p video but not in the Tube environment.

Comment: Of all the answers here, this is the only one that worked for me in June 2015.

Comment: Still works! Tho it goes to a standalone screen and doesn't autoplay.

Comment: @DrZ214 If you add &autoplay=1 to the end of the URL it will autoplay too.