# Is there a way to link someone to a YouTube Video in HD 1080p quality?

Tags: video, youtube

Is there a way to link someone to a YouTube Video in HD 1080p quality? As of right now, when linking someone to a youtube URL, the video defaults to 360p.

Comment: I think the user gets to decide what quality he wants. There's an option in YouTube for your personal default quality, and I don't think you can force the user to use 1080p.

Comment: there may be a way using the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), i know you can request only HD videos, there maybe a way to present it in only HD..

Comment: bummer :( yeah it looks like there is a way with the youtube data api but i am just curious if there is a way to link someone to a url that forces playback in 1080p HD. i heard it was possible by concatenating a string at the end of the URL but it doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: Paul is right below, works well on Mac with Safari, Chrome and Firefox (but for mobile browsers). For 4K, for instance --> https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO-ID?version=3&vq=hd2160

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/kObNpTFPV5c?vq=hd1440
https://www.youtube.com/embed/kObNpTFPV5c?vq=hd1080
etc...
```

Options are:

Code for 1440: `vq=hd1440`
Code for 1080: `vq=hd1080`
Code for 720: `vq=hd720`
Code for 480p: `vq=large`
Code for 360p: `vq=medium`
Code for 240p: `vq=small`

**UPDATE**
As of **10 of April 2018**, this code still works.
Some users reported "not working", if it doesn't work for you, please read below:

From what I've learned,  the problem is related with network speed and or screen size.
When YT player starts, it collects the network speed, screen and player sizes, among other information, if the connection is slow or the screen/player size smaller than the quality requested(`vq=`), a lower quality video is displayed **despite the option selected on `vq=`.**

Also make sure you **read the comments below**.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to set the quality high but set the screen size smaller than full screen?

Comment: Use an iframe and set `height=Xpx` and `width=Xpx`

Comment: ex: `<iframe width="420px" height="345px"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?vq=hd1080">
</iframe>`

Comment: Oh. This is a question for a direct  url to a friend. Is it possible to do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/98LoiMZ59Jw?vq=hd1080?height=345px?width=420px

Comment: Nop, to specify the size you need to embed the video inside an iframe

Comment: why google why?! they need to add that capability!

Comment: looks like this no longer works

Comment: It does not appear to make any difference whether vq= is specified.

YouTube auto selects the best resolution based on the window size and I would presume connection speed as well

Comment: Looks like it's no longer working. I used to be adding `&hd=1` to the URL, but this stopped working. Was Googeling around and found this article, but adding `&vq=hd1080` seems to have stopped working too. If you change `watch?` to `watch_popup?`, together with adding the `vq`tag, it'll show the video in fullscreen (via embed-URL), but some movies (like those of Vevo), don't allow you to watch the video from site other than `youtube.com/...`

Comment: @vol7ron, the down vote it really doesn't matter, what's important here is to understand why the code works for me (and others) and not for you. Are you on a mobile network or using a mobile device ? Can you please provide more info?

Comment: Make an edit and I'll remove my vote and vote this up (just change the date to 4/1/2015). It seems to work on most videos and not others (yes they have the higher quality encoding listed as an option and were embedded links) -- I too am curious about the anomaly.

Comment: This does not work on the latest Chrome on OS X Yosemite. I haven't tried on other browsers. I'm not on mobile, just a regular ol' browser.

Comment: @dpk This works for some users and it doesn't for others. The question is to understand why. I've tested it myself and it works. I guess it's related with the speed of the user's network.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the video or channel itself. Maybe streams for "partners" start out at higher quality than regular folks. Here's a video I just uploaded that always starts at super low quality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_sqhA2KKNQ

Comment: Here's what I've learned about the video you posted. If I play the video inside an small iframe, the default quality is set to `360p`. If I copy the iframe url and pasted it directly on the browser `https://www.youtube.com/embed/d_sqhA2KKNQ?vq=hd1080&html5=1` the video plays at `720p` by default, in both cases the `vq=` was ignored.

Comment: This doesn't work or at least not on every computer and browser i've tested it on. It depends on the size of the frame.

Comment: This doesn't work but appending ?hd=1  worked.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: You just edited to "As of 10 of April 2018, this code still works." which I feel is misleading. It MAY work sometimes, but some other time it doesn't. You also state that "it measures the network speed and the screen and player sizes". So, by that, you're basically saying I CANNOT force HD as YT will still do whatever it wants in case of low network speed/screen resolution. From my perspective this is a false positive. If it was a valid parameter, Google would document it and as per my answer, `vq` isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: If someone reading this than you should looking for solution. And it's all about adding `rel=0` query params to existing `vq`. `vq=large` - not works, but `vq=large&rel=0` works.

Comment: Does 2160 works as vq parameter? I can't test it here.

Answer (score 14):

No, this is not working. And it's not just for you, in case you spent the last hour trying to find an answer for having your embeded videos open in HD.

*Question:* Oh, but how do you know this is not working anymore and **there is no other alternative to make embeded videos open in a different quality**?

*Answer:* Just went to [Google's official documentation regarding Youtube's player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) and there is not a single parameter that allows you to change its quality.

Also, `hd=1` doesn't work either. [More info here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_03_29_2012).

Apparently Youtube analyses the width and height of the user's window (or iframe) and automatically sets the quality based on this.

**UPDATE:**

As of **10 of April of 2018** it still **doesn't** work ([see my comment on the accepted answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145257/is-there-a-way-to-link-someone-to-a-youtube-video-in-hd-1080p-quality#comment86530423_23147137)).

What I can see from comments is that it MAY work sometimes, but some others it doesn't. The accepted answer states that "it measures the network speed and the screen and player sizes". So, by that, we can understand that I CANNOT force HD as YouTube will still do whatever it wants in case of low network speed/screen resolution. From my perspective everyone saying it works just have false positives on their hands and on the occasion they tested it worked for some random reason not related to the `vq` parameter. If it was a valid parameter, Google would document it somewhere, and `vq` isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: I guess you could say "__it's not working for me__".

Comment: The documentation states that they don't support manually setting the quality. In fact, `vq` isn't even documented at all, so I guess this parameter doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: hd=1 just worked for me right now :-) At least it seems like it.

Comment: Can you please make sure it worked for you? Otherwise you may mislead people that came here looking for help. :)

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @NehaK that's basically what I said: it doesn't work and there's no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To link to a YouTube video so it plays in HD by default, use the following URL:

https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?version=3&vq=hd1080

Change VIDEOID to the YouTube video ID that you want to link to. When someone follows the link, it will display the highest-resolution available (up to 1080p) in full-screen mode. Unfortunately, vq=hd1080 does not work on the normal YouTube site (with comments and related videos).

Comment: How do you link to 60FPS?

Comment: Works well on desktop (Mac) browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome). Thanks. But not on mobile.

Comment: THAT WORKED FOR ME!!

Comment: not working for me