# only download 720p/mp4 from youtube in php

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-dl

Hello I am putting a site to play videos on youtube from a link. I have already set up a page in php to get the MP4 link (get_video_info). My problem is that when the script displays the result, it shows several formats like 720p, 1080p and others.
I would like to only get the link in 720p and have it play directly.

test page: https://teldoo.net/ydl/

My youtube.php

```
<?php Class YouTubeDownloader {


public function getYouTubeCode($url) {
    parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $vars );
    return $vars['v'];
}


public function processVideo($vid) {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("https://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$vid),$info);


    $playabilityJson = json_decode($info['player_response']);
    $formats = $playabilityJson->streamingData->formats;
    $adaptiveFormats = $playabilityJson->streamingData->adaptiveFormats;

    $IsPlayable = $playabilityJson->playabilityStatus->status;

    if(strtolower($IsPlayable) != 'ok') {
        $log = date("c")." ".$info['player_response']."\n";
        file_put_contents('./video.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
    }

    $result = array();

    if(!empty($info) && $info['status'] == 'ok' && strtolower($IsPlayable) == 'ok') {
        $i=0;
        foreach($adaptiveFormats as $stream) {

            $streamUrl = $stream->url;
            $type = explode(";", $stream->mimeType);

            $qualityLabel='';
            if(!empty($stream->qualityLabel)) {
                $qualityLabel = $stream->qualityLabel;
            }

            $videoOptions[$i]['link'] = $streamUrl;
            $videoOptions[$i]['type'] = 'video/mp4';
            $videoOptions[$i]['quality'] = $qualityLabel;
            $i++;
        }
        $j=0;
        foreach($formats as $stream) {

            $streamUrl = $stream->url;
            $type = explode(";", $stream->mimeType);

            $qualityLabel='';
            if(!empty($stream->qualityLabel)) {
                $qualityLabel = $stream->qualityLabel;
            }

            $videoOptionsOrg[$j]['link'] = $streamUrl;
            $videoOptionsOrg[$j]['type'] = $type[0];
            $videoOptionsOrg[$j]['quality'] = $qualityLabel;
            $j++;
        }
        $result['videos'] = array(
            'info'=>$info,
            'adapativeFormats'=>$videoOptions,
            'formats'=>$videoOptionsOrg
        );
        
        
        return $result;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}}
```

My index.php

```
<?php
require_once "class.youtube.php";
$yt  = new YouTubeDownloader();
$downloadLinks ='';
$error='';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $videoLink = $_POST['video_link'];
    if(!empty($videoLink)) {
        $vid = $yt->getYouTubeCode($videoLink);
        if($vid) {
            $result = $yt->processVideo($vid);
            
            if($result) {
                //print_r($result);
                $info = $result['videos']['info'];
                $formats = $result['videos']['formats'];
                $adapativeFormats = $result['videos']['adapativeFormats'];

                

                $videoInfo = json_decode($info['player_response']);

                $title = $videoInfo->videoDetails->title;
                $thumbnail = $videoInfo->videoDetails->thumbnail->thumbnails->url;
            }
            else {
                $error = "Something went wrong";
            }

        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "Please enter a YouTube video URL";
    }
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" class="h-100">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>YouTube video</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
        .formSmall {
            width: 700px;
            margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="" class="formSmall">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="video_link" placeholder="Coller le lien">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
                      </span>
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->
        </form>

        <?php if($error) :?>
            <div style="color:red;font-weight: bold;text-align: center"><?php print $error?></div>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if(!empty($formats)):?>
        <div class="row formSmall">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <?php print $title?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card formSmall">
            <div class="card-header">
                <strong>With Video & Sound</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table ">
                    <tr>
                        <td> Type </td>
                        <td> Qualité </td>
                        <td> Télécharger </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($formats as $video) :?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php print $video['type']?></td>
                            <td><?php print $video['quality']?></td>
                            <td><a href="downloader.php?link=<?php print urlencode($video['link'])?>&title=<?php print urlencode($title)?>&type=<?php print urlencode($video['type'])?>">Download</a> </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

Comment: [May be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145257/is-there-a-way-to-link-someone-to-a-youtube-video-in-hd-1080p-quality)

Comment: So, is the question essentially just how to write an `if` for `$video['quality']`? Then, how did you manage to craft the rest of that code?