# change YouTube video quality settings from ADB

Tags: automation, youtube, adb

I wanted to change the YouTube video quality from `adb`.
Currently I am using the following command to run the YouTube video from adb:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv11L-ZfrSg"
```

is there any additional option to set it to required quality?

Comment: Have you tried the parameters mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145257/is-there-a-way-to-link-someone-to-a-youtube-video-in-hd-1080p-quality

Comment: adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv11L-ZfrSg?vq=hd1440"
i tried above, was not working for me.